# Rails quickly find record where has_many associations exactly match array of association ids

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I've got a `Product` model which `has_many` `OptionValue` records, which describe `color`, `size`, etc.

Within my code, I need to query the Product model where the `product.option_values.pluck(:id)` array exactly matches an array of (e.g.) `options = [1, 6, 4]`.

Running something like `Product.includes(:option_values).where(option_values: { id: options_array })` returns all values that match at least one element of the options array, rather than all of them.

I've developed an inefficient way of getting the record I need, as follows:

```
Product.all.each { |v| return v if v.option_values.pluck(:id).sort == options_array.sort }
```

Obviously the above is way ott and I'm sure there's a simpler way to handle this, and I'm happy to use ActiveRecord or a straight SQL query (though I'm not too hot on the latter, so haven't come up with anything yet).

Any advice on the best way of achieving this greatly appreciated. Not sure I've explained this perfectly, so please comment if you've any questions.

Thanks in advance, Steve.

Comment: If a Product has options [1,4,6,9] and your search criteria is [1,4,6], what should happen?  Is that a match *(because the product contains all the criteria you searched for)*?  Or is it a mis-match *(because the product has at least one OptionValue that you didn't search for)*?

Comment: @MatBailie - thanks for the quick response. I'm looking at _exact_ matches, so that scenario shouldn't return the product.

Comment: I don't know the RubyOnRails notation, but the SQL is straight forward `SELECT o.product_id FROM OptionValue o WHERE o.option_id IN (1,4,6) GROUP BY o.product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`

Comment: @SRack
I need similar thing.
Whats the solution you found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clocked this in my old questions and threw together a quick and easy solution, so dropping it here for anyone else that might come this way:

```
product_options = product.option_values.pluck(:id)
unless options_array.length < product_options.length
  (product_options & options_array).length == product_options.length
end
```

This:

- checks the `options_array` is long enough to contain the necessary matches
- looks for the elements in common across the two arrays (`(product_options & options_array)`)
- measures their length
- checks this is the same length as the desired array `product_options`, meaning all the required options were found.

Alternatively, you can subtract one from the other and check there's nothing leftover (i.e. missing):

```
(product_options - options_array).empty?
```

Hope this helps someone at some point.